# Show username when posting comments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app when users post album reviews called Pins. I created a comments model for other users to comment on the reviews. I'm struggling getting the comments to say "Posted by" and then show the user's name who posts them. Here is some of the code:

The pins model `has_many :comments`
The user model `has_many :comments`
The comments model `belongs_to :pin`
                   `belongs_to :user`

Here's the comments controller:

```
def create
@pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
@comment = @pin.comments.create(params[:comment])
@comment.username = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Here is the app as it is now:
http://powerful-reaches-7038.herokuapp.com

I've tried some of the other answers posted on Stack Overflow, but no dice. I'm trying to say something like:

```
<strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago by <%= comment.user.name %></strong>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `@comment.username = current_user` be `@comment.user = current_user` in your `create` action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a `User` instance to the username field for the `Comment`. I assume that the username attribute is a string in the database. So if you want the name to appear in the comment then you need to assign it the name from the current user.

So:

```
@comment.username = current_user.name
```

If you already have an association between `Comment` and `User` then you could do:

```
@comment.user = current_user

<%= @comment.user.name %>
```

Comment: If I do <%= current_user %>, then it works perfectly while I'm signed in. (I know its not supposed to be that way, but at least it means it's close to working) It's recognizing the user's name, so there's some issue with saving the name. When I do @comment.user = current_user, then <%= comment.user.name %> it says undefined method name. Since comment belongs_to :user, shouldn't comment.user.name work?

Comment: It should work. Have you deleted all comments after updating the code to `@comment.user = current_user`? Previous comments would have a nil user and would fail.

Comment: I'll try that, but would that cause the error of undefined method name when I use comment.user.name?

Comment: It worked! Deleting the old comments did the trick! It doesn't give you any hint that the old comments are the problem, so it would have taken me forever to stumble onto that. Thanks roo and everyone!

Comment: Your welcome. The hint was the error 'undefined method name for nil' which meant that a comment had a nil user. Add a `validates_presence_of :user` to your comment model and it will stop this from happening in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You save the username in

```
@comment.username = current_user
```

and show it with:

```
<%= comment.user.name %>
```

but it have to be

```
<%= comment.username %>
```

Comment: If I do `@comment.user = current_user` in the create action, and then `<%= comment.user %>` in the show view, I get: "Posted 3 minutes ago by #<User:0x007f89f93bbcc8>". IF I do `@comment.username = current_user` and either `<%= comment.user.name %>` or `<%= comment.username %>` I get an error of undefined method name or username