# How can I show comment username in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a simple blog with authentication, and I'm stuck with a little problem - I need the comment belong to current user and display his name. so:

1. I created a User model with `username:string`
2. **Post.rb** `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy`
3. **User.rb** `has_many :comments`
4. **Comment.rb** `belongs_to :post belongs_to :user`
5. I mage a migration `addUserIdToComments user_id:integer`
6. In **comments_controller.rb** I wrote `@comment.user = current_user`
7. In my view I have `<%= comment.user.username %>`

In result I have a `NameError undefined local variable or method comment for #<#<Class:0xb93859dc>:0xb4b2a2b4>`
I've already looked over  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434786/show-username-when-posting-comments-in-rails), but it didn't help :(

**`comments_controller.rb`**

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'comments/form'
    end
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:username, :body)
end
```

**`show.html.erb`**

```
<div id="post_content">
    <h2><%= @post.title %></h2>
    <p><%= @post.body %></p>
</div>
<div id="comments">
    <h2 class="comments">Комментариев: <%= @post.comments.count %></h2>
    <%= render @post.comments %>
    <%= render "comments/form" %>
</div>
```

**`_comment.html.erb`**

```
<div class="comment_content">
    <p><%= comment.user.username %></p>
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>
    <p><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></p>
</div>
```

**`_form.html.erb`**

```
<div id="comment_form">
    <h3 class="form_title">Оставить комментарий</h3>
    <p><%= comment.user.username %></p>
    <%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
        <p>
            <%= f.label :Комментарий %>
            <%= f.text_area :body %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= f.submit %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you calling `comment` instead of `@comment` in your view ? are you looping through some @comments variable ?

Comment: @KarimMortabit yes, in my `show.html.erb` I have `<%= render @post.comments %>`

Comment: Show controller and view (including subviews for `render`) code

Comment: I guess problem is in comments/form partial can you share that one.

Comment: Please next time show code in question but not in comments.
Own questions and answers are editable without any limits. Now I moved code to question myself.
And where is `def show`?

Comment: @GeneralFailure ok, I'm sorry, thanks! `def show`, as well as `show.html.erb` belongs to `Post`. I have comments displayed and the comment creation form in the Post view

Comment: Just noticed that this question was marked so negative, which surprised me at first as it looked well built. Edit history showed it started in a much worse state. Congrats to OP & General Failure for editing it into shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what is `<%= render @post.comments %>` and where is a view for it, I see subview only for one comment

Try change

```
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

to

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment_content">
        <p><%= comment.user.username %></p>
        <p><%= comment.body %></p>
        <p><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Or check you subview that uses by `@post.comments`

Comment: `<%= render @post.comments %>` renders the `_comment.html.erb` partial. I've tried your variant, and it still gives back an error, in `_form.html.erb`, in `<p><%= comment.user.username %></p>` line

Comment: Does `_from.html.erb` know `comment`? In some cases comment is not created yet. Check `comment` variable for `nil` and `defined`, and if it not exists, show just `current_user.name`, but it can be `nil` too if user is not signed in!.

Comment: thank you! I've changed this line to `current_user.username`, and it worked, but now, when creating a comment, it just doesn't show `username` (though user is signed in)

Comment: `comment.nil? ? current_user.username : comment.user.username`

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but I've done as you've just said and now it returns the same error `undefined local variable or method 'comment' for #<#<Class:0xb47bfd2c>:0xb1db9154>` :(( may be I've just done something wrong when assigning the very User model with `username:string`...

Comment: Check by `defined? comment`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107333/discussion-between-alexnikolaev94-and-general-failure).